# Avoid unpleasant skipping when implementing sticky navigator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a sticky navigator to my blog which will stay on the very top when scrolling down. Simply enough I used jQuery and `.scrollTop()`.

```
$("document").ready(function($){
    /* Sticky Navigation Bar */
    var nav = $('nav');
    $(window).scroll(function () {    
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 125) {
            nav.addClass("fixed-nav");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("fixed-nav");
        }
    });
});
```

With `fixed-nav` being positioned fixed in CSS

```
.fixed-nav {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

It works certainly (See [my blog](http://cmade.github.io/)). Nevertheless I got a small but really annoying problem. When you scroll the page from top to down, you'll notice that right before the navigation bar becomes `fixed`, contents below it will jump upwards a little. I know the reason is `fixed` positioning brought the navigator out of the stream so following content jumps up to refill its position. But I don't know how to avoid this. Can anyone come up with any idea?

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to toggle a `nav-fixed` class on your body, and then add a `margin-top` to your `#main` div which matches the height of the nav whilst it was positioned statically.

```
.nav-fixed nav {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

/* Identical to nav's height */
.nav-fixed #main {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```